# How to make the scroll menu span across the pages of my html output?

Tags: html, r-markdown, scrollbar, knitr

I have two more pages which begin this way, each with their own scrolling menu, I would like to make a sigle one for all of them. Then I need to run knitr on them for a html page
    ---
    title: "page"
    author: "me"
    date: "26/02/2020"
    output:
      html_document:
        toc: yes
        toc_depth: 3
        toc_float:
          collapsed: yes
          smooth_scroll: yes
      word_document: default
    ---

```
<style type="text/css">

body{ /* Normal  */
      font-size: 14px;
  }
td {  /* Table  */
  font-size: 12px;
}
h1.title {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: DarkRed;
}
h1 { /* Header 1 */
  font-size: 28px;
  color: DarkBlue;
}
h2 { /* Header 2 */
    font-size: 22px;
  color: DarkBlue;
}
h3 { /* Header 3 */
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: DarkBlue;
}
code.r{ /* Code block */
    font-size: 12px;
}
pre { /* Code block - determines code spacing between lines */
    font-size: 12px;
}
</style>

<style type="text/css">

#TOC {
  margin: 25px 0px 20px 0px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
#TOC {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
}


.toc-content {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

div.main-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
}

div.tocify {
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 260px;
  max-height: 85%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  div.tocify {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  div.tocify {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
  }
}

.tocify ul, .tocify li {
  line-height: 20px;
}

.tocify-subheader .tocify-item {
  font-size: 1.00em;
  padding-left: 25px;
  text-indent: 0;
}

.tocify .list-group-item {
  border-radius: 0px;
}


</style>
```

Comment: Looks like you have unformatted YAML before your code block? Would you mind fixing to make the question a little clearer?

Comment: hi and thanks fo your answer, I reformulated the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61382869/how-to-include-all-chapters-in-toc-in-different-html-pages